# What are the elements of this Set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$A = \{n \in \mathbb{N} : 1 \leq n^2 \leq 10 \}$

Are the elements of A $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ or $\{1,4,9\}$ or $\{1,2,3\}$?

Which one is correct?

Thank you very much for helps...

Comment: $A$ is the set of natural numbers whose squares are between $1$ and $10$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last answer $\{1,2,3\}$ is correct. Each if those numbers satisfy $1 \leq n^2 \leq 10$.

Your first answer would satisfy

$1 \leq n \leq 10$

And your second

$1 \leq n \leq 10$ and $n$ is a square number; or more formally $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}: n = k^2$

Comment: thank you that was helpful

Answer (score 0):

$A = \{n \in \mathbb{N} : 1 \leq n^2 \leq 10 \} = \{1,2,3\}$

$ B = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 \} = \{n \in \mathbb{N} : 1 \leq n \leq 10 \} $

$C = \{1,4,9\} = \{n^2: n \in \mathbb{N}, 1 \leq n^2 \leq 10 \} $